# Combine results into one line

Tags: sql

How do I make these results appear on one line, in SQL?

[image]

Comment: What have you tried? Show us your code and any error messages - it will be easier to assist.

Comment: Group by the first three columns and aggregate the last two?

Comment: The script is a little long, but in the select statement, I am entering CASE WHEN gen.GENDER = 'F' THEN COUNT(gen.[NAME-ID]) END AS FEMALE,
  CASE WHEN gen.GENDER = 'M' THEN COUNT(gen.[NAME-ID]) END AS FMALE

Comment: Those are the two lines that are giving me issues...No error messages.  I just need for the results to be one row: SCHOOL_ID, SCHOOL_NAME, GRADE, FEMALE, MALE

Comment: @user3491260 can you give your table as it exists now along with the data in it? Thanks

Comment: It's fixed.  @MartinSmith suggestion worked.  Thanks, everyone!

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add the tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `db2`, `sql-server`, ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a GROUP BY to do this:

```
SELECT school_id, school_name, grade, SUM(CASE WHEN Gender='F' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as female, SUM(CASE WHEN Gender='M' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as male
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY school_id, school_name, grade;
```

Comment: Okay.  I will try this.  Thank you.

Comment: It worked.  I forgot to update my group by. Thanks, everyone!

Comment: You see two rows per school ID, name, and grade as in your question? That's not really possible given the query.

Comment: I just changed it around as `sum()` makes more sense here.

Comment: After this, if you are seeing more than one record for each distinct combination of `school_id`, `school_name` and `grade` then something else is funky in your data. This query should do exactly what you need.

Comment: @JNevill your first suggestion worked.  I just needed to update the group by.  Once I did, along with the other logic, I am now only seeing one distinct row.  I appreciate the help!

Comment: Great to hear it!

Comment: @user3491260 if this answer solved your question, don't forget to accept it by clicking the green checkmark!

Comment: @Callat Thank you.  I am new to the forum, and forgot that I should click the check mark.  I have clicked it, now.  I appreciate the reminder.